# How to query data from MySQL through Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to Node and learning how to query data from MySQL.
I get the following error:

> err { [Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database '201803028']
>     code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
>     errno: 1049,
>     sqlMessage: 'Unknown database \'201803028\'',
>     sqlState: '42000',
>     fatal: true }

here is my code

> const mysql = require('mysql');
>
> var db = 
>   mysql.createConnection({
>      host:'localhost',
>      user:'root',
>      password:'123456',
>      database:'201803028'});
>
> db.query('SELECT * FROM `user-table`;',(err,data)=>{ 
>     if(err){ 
>      console.log('err',err); 
>     }else{ 
>      console.log('success',data); 
>     } 
>    })

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The database `201803028` does not exist. You should create it before you connect to it.

Comment: Is `201803028` correct? It might be `20180328`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'yourpassword',
  database : 'yourdatabasename'
})

connection.connect();
/* Uncomment the below query to test your connction
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});*/
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation in addition to the code example?